# added text node to SVG group with javascript but does not appear

Tags: javascript, text, svg, addition

This is Javascript that is in the SVG file inside  tags.

This SVG shows a timeline of bands in my city.
When the mouse clicks on a , the script accesses an XML library and retrieves the names of the members in each band, when they joined. and adds a new text node to the SVG group that contains the .

this is the first one:

```
   <g class="band" id="hajimama">
<text x="633.333333333" y="50" fill="black" font-size="12">Hajimama</text>
    <rect x="633.333333333" y="50" width="413.333333333" height="15" fill="red" onmousedown="growBox(evt);"></rect></g>
```

this is the growBox() function:

```
    function growBox(evt)
{
 var i, g_index;
 var r = evt.target;

 g_index = find_SVGBand(r);

 b = find_XMLBand(b_name);
 members = b.getElementsByTagName("member"); //members.length is used for drawing.
 stretch = members.length*16;

 for (k=g_index+1;k<groups.length;k++)
 {
  cur_y = parseFloat(get_firstChild(groups[k]).getAttribute("y"));
  new_y = cur_y + stretch;
  get_firstChild(groups[k]).setAttribute("y",new_y);
  groups[k].getElementsByTagName("rect")[0].setAttribute("y",new_y);
 }
 evt.target.setAttribute('height',stretch);

 var s = parseFloat(r.getAttribute("y")) + 5; //write the first member name below the band name
 for (k=0;k<members.length;k++) //loop through each member of a band
 {
    var m=members[k];
    var m_name = returnMemberName(m);

    q = document.createElement("text");
    q.setAttribute("font-size",20);

    if (m.getElementsByTagName("instrument")[0].hasChildNodes())
    {
        if (m.getElementsByTagName("instrument")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == "guitar")
            inst_clr="#993333";
        else if (m.getElementsByTagName("instrument")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == "bass")
            inst_clr="#339933";
        else if (m.getElementsByTagName("instrument")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == "drums")
            inst_clr="#333399";
    }
    else
        inst_clr="#000000";

    q.setAttribute("fill",inst_clr);

    //draw names based on start dates
    m_start = returnMemberJoinDate(m);
    mrect_start = (m_start - 2000) * 80;

    q.setAttribute("x",mrect_start);
    q.setAttribute("y",s);
    mn = document.createTextNode(m_name);
    q.appendChild(mn);
    r.parentNode.appendChild(q);
    q.setAttribute('visibility','visible');
    s+=15;
   alert(r.parentNode.getAttribute("id") + " " + get_lastChild(r.parentNode).nodeName + " " + get_lastChild(r.parentNode).childNodes[0].nodeValue);
 } //for

 evt.target.setAttribute('onmousedown','');
 addEBox(evt);
}
```

as you can see by the alert() the data is properly accessed and the node are properly appended to the   node because r.parentNode.getAttribute("id") returns the id of the  node.

any ideas why the text doesn't appear?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SVG elements must be created in the SVG namespace. This means that createElement won't create an SVG text element, you need createElementNS instead.

So

```
q = document.createElement("text");
```

should be

```
q = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot. i tried NS before but it didn't work because of other errors :)  but that simple change worked great. I must admit I don't really understand NameSpace at all :)

Answer (score 0):

Roberts code above works for me on IE11, Thanks Robert!.

At first I got Object doesn't support property or method 'createElementNS' but found this was due to compatibility mode being enabled on that page, once I removed it things worked fine.